# Can I use Amazon S3 to auto host my images without using W3 Total Cache?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, caching

I am using a wordpress site, and using the Formidable Pro plugin to create forms for users to submit pictures frontend as posts.

As the form is created using formidable, any pictures uploaded by user goes to a upload folder in the formidable directory in my FTP.

I want to use Amazon S3 to host all the images uploaded by users and also for these images to be shown in posts like how it was supposed to work.

How do I go about doing this? Must I use a W3 total cache plugin or super cache plugin? Is there another alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the S3 and Cloudfront plugin you can try

http://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/

The only caveat to this, is that the images are loaded onto your server first, then uploaded to S3.

Comment: Thanks! Was looking at that too, what is the downside of having the images loaded onto my server first? Another thing, it says it 'automatically copies images, videos, documents, and any other media added through WordPress' media uploader to Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3)', most of the pictures won't be uploaded through wordpress's media loader, but through the form I created using Formidable Pro, so will it work?

Comment: No real downside as this plugin has the option to delete them after they have been uploaded, was more of a concern if they would be in two places for no real reason.

It should work, as long as Formidable Pro writes to the upload directory in the same way as the standard Wordpress uploader.

Comment: I had some difficulty with this, because the official Amazon Web Services SDK requires PHP 5.3.3 or higher.

Comment: I have managed to update my PHP to the requirement and set up the plugin. Now I have another question, so when images are first loaded onto my server first, does that mean my posts' pictures will first be pointed to mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/picture_file.jpg but subsequently it will point to the bucket address? Under Plugin settings I have the following ticked : 1. Copy files to S3 as they are uploaded to the Media Library 2. Point file URLs to S3/CloudFront for files that have been copied to S3 3. Remove uploaded file from local filesystem once it has been copied to S3

Comment: That sounds correct, I've seen a couple of comments about the plugin not deleting images from your server after they have been uploaded. One to keep an eye on

Comment: oh i see, been a day already, but my posts' pictures still pointing to mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/picture_file.jpg Guess I'll try to see what could be causing the problem. Thanks Pete!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install a plugin to do this for you.

For example, there this plugin that's allows you to put a shortcode on any post/page to show S3 files: http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-aws-s3-browser/6470423

Check out the Live DEMO here: http://www.awss3.redwanhilali.net/?page_id=5#

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service like [img.vision](https://img.vision).

It has a plugin at wordpress.org: https://wordpress.org/plugins/img-vision-button/

**Steps:**

1. Upload images at img.vision
2. Install plugin into your wordpress (you'll need to grab your api key from img.vision)
3. Create pages or posts and use the Img.vision button to add images from your account

Disclaimer: I created this service and after the 30 day trial you need to pay for a max image limit. NO need to pay for S3 or CDN bandwidth separately.